# FormTextField - initialValue not working from persistend data

Tags: flutter

I want to show as initial email and password values from values stored in shared preferences.
For that I created the autoLogin method and used the initialValue property of TextField.
However these fields continue to appear blank.
What am I doing wrong?

```
   void  autoLogin() async {

       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       var autoLogin = (prefs.getInt('autoLogin') ?? 10);
       if (autoLogin == 1) {
       setState(() {
          _email = prefs.getString('email');
          print(_email);
       });

    }


    @override
    void initState() {

      autoLogin();
      super.initState();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(context) {
   return Scaffold(
       ....
       TextFormField(
       initialValue: _email,
       ....
```

Comment: What is the autoLogin integer? Is it supposed to act as a boolean?

Comment: create a controller and pass the value that you want show as initial value to controller.text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100736/how-to-change-dynamically-a-initialvalue-in-flutter?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here, I've defined a controller and set its value in the autoLogin() function as Chinky said.

```dart
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

   void  autoLogin() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       var autoLogin = prefs.getInt('autoLogin') ?? 10; // still don't know what this is, a boolean?
       if (autoLogin == 1) {
           setState(() {
              _controller.text = prefs.getString('email');
           });
       }
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      autoLogin();
   }



   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
           ....
           TextFormField(
           controller: _controller,
           initialValue: "", // set it to a string by default
           ....
```